# Create a output file from file stream

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to c++ and yes this is a homework assignment.
I am considering a switch statement instead of the if else statements in my function.

I am trying to write information read from an input filestream, to an output file after the data has been manipulated.

The prgram is supposed to read information from a file, process it and then display the data on the console and also write the result to an output file, the program should ask the user to enter the filename for both input and output files.

I cannot get my program to create a file. It works with files that already exist though.

Please help me with getting my program to create a file if it does not exist.

Oh and this is in c++

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

MY CODE :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

char getNumber(char l);

int main ()
{
     string s1 = "D:\\Unisa\\Assignment_stuffs\\COS1512\\Assignment\\";
     string inFile, outFile;

     cout << " Please enter the input filename: ";
     cin >> inFile;
     cout << "\nPlease enter the output filename: ";
     cin >> outFile;

     string inFileAdd = s1 + inFile;
     string inFileAdd2 = s1 + outFile;

     ifstream in_stream;
     ofstream out_stream;
     in_stream.open(inFileAdd.c_str(), ios::in);
     if (in_stream.fail())
     {
        cout << "Error!! Input file opening failed.";
        exit(1);
     }
     out_stream.open(inFileAdd2.c_str(), ios::out);
     if (out_stream.fail())
     {
        cout << "Error!! Output file opening failed.";
        exit(1);
     }   

     char next = ' ';
     string letter;

          while (!in_stream.eof()) 
          {
                in_stream.get(next);
                while (next != '\n')
                {
                        cout << next;
                        out_stream.put(next);
                        letter = letter + getNumber(next);
                        in_stream.get(next); 
                }
               cout << " " + letter;
               out_stream << " " + letter << endl;

               letter = "";
               cout << endl;
          }


     in_stream.close();

    return 0;
}

char getNumber(char l)
{
     if ((l == 'A') || (l == 'a') || (l == 'B') || (l == 'b') || (l == 'C') || (l == 'c'))
     {
            return '2';
     }
     else if ((l == 'D') || (l == 'd') || (l == 'E') || (l == 'e') || (l == 'F') || (l == 'f'))
     {
          return '3';
     }
     else if ((l == 'G') || (l == 'g') || (l == 'H') || (l == 'h') || (l == 'I') || (l == 'i'))
     {
          return '4';
     }
     else if ((l == 'J') || (l == 'j') || (l == 'K') || (l == 'k') || (l == 'L') || (l == 'l'))
     {
          return '5';
     }
     else if ((l == 'M') || (l == 'm') || (l == 'N') || (l == 'n') || (l == 'O') || (l == 'o'))
     {
          return '6';
     }
     else if ((l == 'P') || (l == 'p') || (l == 'Q') || (l == 'q') || (l == 'R') || (l == 'r') || (l == 'S') || (l == 's'))
     {
          return '7';
     }
     else if ((l == 'T') || (l == 't') || (l == 'U') || (l == 'u') || (l == 'V') || (l == 'v'))
     {
          return '8';
     }
     else if ((l == 'W') || (l == 'w') || (l == 'X') || (l == 'x') || (l == 'Y') || (l == 'y') || (l == 'Z') || (l == 'z'))
     {
          return '9';
     }
}
```

Comment: Does your program have proper permissions to create a file at `D:\Unisa\Assignment_stuffs\COS1512\Assignment`? It is possible to have permission to write to a file that exists, but not create a new one.

Comment: For ifstream and ofstream classes, ios::in and ios::out are automatically and respectively assumed, so you don't really need them.

Comment: It is vitally important to learn to minimize your code, and develop the different pieces in isolation. Try writing *the simplest program that will write to a new file*. You'll either discover the problem on your own, or some up with an example that we can run. (My money's on @millsj.)

Comment: One other thing to note: you don't _have_ to call `close` on out_stream, and you aren't, but if you _do_, you can check `fail()` on out_stream afterwards to see if it was successful in writing the file. This is one other place to check for failures.

Answer (score 1):

Do what Beta said and create a **minimal** file opening and writing program first. Get that working. Then build the rest of the needed functionality around that, compiling and fixing errors every step of the way. If you can get this working, add a little bit of your desired functionality to it.  Look into permissions on the directory you are writing to if this doesn't work.  This compiles in visual studio, you may need to include other libraries on linux/unix/mac:

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream file;

    file.open("file.txt");      //open a file

    file<<"Hello file\n";       //write to it

    file.close();           //close it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called "FileMonitor" that has a private member variable for the filename
and a public method "monitorFile" that continuously checks if the contents of the file
have been modified and performs some action if they have

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).